# Performance monitoring and impact analysis

Tags: monitoring, automation

Im looking for advice on SW which can monitor performance impact of each application running on laptop/server and also what are the conditions of higher load (e.g. when application XYZ is executed).

Our use-case:

- Testing of performance impact on system using new application
- Testing of -II- using newer version of already used application
- Comparison of impact before/after

Key requirements:

- Metrics: CPU, Mem, Disk IO, IRQ, Network, ...
- Monitoring & Metrics for each individual application running in
  system
- Timeline showing impact during the whole day

Nice to have:

- Subsystem for tasks automation in order to create extra load on
  system

Thanks a lot in advance for any recommendation

Comment: please Update your question and tell us which operating System is me aned, however this may be purly opinion driven which may out of focus

Comment: Windows, macOS & Linux, but Windows is most important